# Apache ODE instance ID

Tags: apache, tomcat, bpel, apache-ode

How to get instance id of BPEL process in Apache ODE at runtime? 
Need to return id as response to calling.

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
<bpelx:exec name="Java_Embedding_1" language="java" version="1.3">
    <![CDATA[ setVariableData("instance", new Long(getInstanceId())); ]]>
</bpelx:exec>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODE doesn't support Oracle's proprietary extensions. Just do the following:

```
<assign>
  <from>$ode:pid</from>
  <to>$instance</to>
</assign>
```